# ASP.NET Core [FromBody] and Minimal API unexpected return value in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, minimal-apis, api-versioning, carter

I have here my Minimal API setup with ASP.NET Core versioning and Carter. `PutMethod`,`PostMethod`, and `PatchMethod` works just fine, but my `GetMethod` and `DeleteMethod` does not return the string.

This is my API Versions and minimal API:

```
public class ApiVersions
{
    public const string vset = "API_Version_Set";
    public static ApiVersion v1 = new ApiVersion(1);
    public static ApiVersion v2 = new ApiVersion(2);
    public static ApiVersion v3 = new ApiVersion(3);
}
```

```
public class GeneralController : ICarterModule
{
    public void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        var group = app.MapGroup("api/v{version:apiVersion}/general")
            .WithTags("General")
            .WithOpenApi()
            .WithApiVersionSet(ApiVersions.vset)
            ;

        group.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
        group.MapDelete("{url}", DeleteMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);

        group.MapPut("{url}", PutMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
        group.MapPost("{url}", PostMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
        group.MapPatch("{url}", PatchMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
    }

    public static string GetMethod(string? url) => "This is from GET";
    public static string DeleteMethod(string? url) => "this is from DELETE.";
    public static string PutMethod(string? url, LoginDTO login) => "this is from PUT";
    public static string PostMethod(LoginDTO login) => "this is from POST.";
    public static string PatchMethod(string? url, LoginDTO login) => "this is from PATCH.";
}
```

and this is my configuration on Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCarter()
    .AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
    .AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersions.v1;
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
}).AddApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});

app.MapCarter().NewApiVersionSet(ApiVersions.vset)
    .HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1)
    .HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v2)
    .HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v3)
    .ReportApiVersions()
    .Build();
```

`GetMethod` and `DeleteMethod` only works properly if I configure some lines on the code:

Method 1: if I change my `GetMethod` and `DeleteMethod` version:

```
group.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v2);
group.MapGet("{url}", DeleteMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v2);
```

Method 2: if I use `[FromRoute]` and remove my `LoginDTO` parameter in `PutMethod`, `PostMethod`, and `PatchMethod`:

```
public static string GetMethod([FromRoute] string url) => "This is from GET";
public static string DeleteMethod([FromRoute] string url) => "this is from DELETE.";
public static string PutMethod([FromRoute] string url) => "this is from PUT";
public static string PostMethod([FromRoute] string url) => "this is from POST.";
public static string PatchMethod([FromRoute] string url) => "this is from PATCH.";
```

Method 3: If i change the path:

```
group.MapPut("put/{url}", PutMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
group.MapPost("post/{url}", PostMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
group.MapPatch("patch/{url}", PatchMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
```

Method 4: If I commented this three:

```
//group.MapPut("{url}", PutMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
//group.MapPost("{url}", PostMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
//group.MapPatch("{url}", PatchMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
```

Comment: Can you please add full [mre]? Including `ApiVersions`, csproj, etc.

Comment: a GET wouldn't have a body... you'd be getting query vars from the URL.

Comment: A minimum of the configuration setup and the API definitions (working and not), will provide more context and lead to a meaningful answer. The root route template will **not** work with a literal value when you version by URL segment. You **must** use the API version route constraint which will resolve based on the corresponding API version metadata. The correct route template is: `app.MapGroup("api/v{version:apiVersion}/general2")`

Comment: Could you reformulate the question, e.g. "Unexpected return value in method ...  with minimal ASP.net Core API", or something similar? What is Blazor? What has it to do with this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I was able to reproduce your scenario. Based on your description, it would appear that things are *working*, but they are not showing up in the Swagger UI. You didn't share that part of your configuration, but I'm guessing it is incorrect. You didn't specify or indicate which OpenAPI generator you're using, but I presume it's Swashbuckle. There's a number of things going on, so let's tackle them one by one.

#### Issue 1 - Undefined Route Parameter

You defined the route template:

```cs
group.MapPost("{url}", PostMethod).HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);
```

but the method:

```cs
public static string PostMethod(LoginDTO login) => "this is from POST.";
```

does **not** have a `url` parameter. This will result in the literal `{url}` being part of the route path.

#### Issue 2 - OpenAPI Doc Generation

Swashbuckle will eager evaluate the setup in `AddSwaggerGen` so we need differ resolution through DI using *Options*. We'll want to use resolve the `IApiVersionDescriptorProvider` from API Versioning which will collate all of the API versions in the application. This will enable you to configure OpenAPI documents without hardcoding anything. The world's simplest implementation would look like:

```cs
public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
{
    private readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;

    public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        => this.provider = provider;

    public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
    {
        foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
        {
            options.SwaggerDoc(
                description.GroupName,
                new()
                {
                    Title = "Example API",
                    Description = "An example application with OpenAPI, " +
                                  "Swashbuckle, and API versioning.",
                    Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                });
        }
    }
}
```

#### Issue 3 - API Version Metadata

You can still explicitly use the older `ApiVersionSet` APIs, but implicitly configuring API versions on the endpoints and/or their groups is arguably more *natural*. There's always an `ApiVersionSet` under the hood. The name associated with the `ApiVersionSet` is the *logical* name of the API and will be used by default when you integrate the API Explorer extensions for OpenAPI.

API version metadata **must** roll up from a root group. When you use group and  endpoint extension methods that behavior is strictly enforced. When you build the `ApiVersionSet` by hand, the rules can only loosely be enforced and there are more opportunities for mistakes. There are likely two approaches that you want to use for configuration. There are other options, but these are the ones you'd likely be interested in.

##### Option 1 - Common Route Template with Nested Groups

This approach configures the route template for all API versions at the root. Each set of endpoints **must** roll up to a group for proper collation, so we need to add a new group (with no route template) to represent the collection of endpoints. By applying the API version on the group, all endpoints in that group will have the API versions defined by the parent group.

```cs
public class GeneralController : ICarterModule
{
    public void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        var general = app.NewVersionedApi("General")
                         .MapGroup("api/v{version:apiVersion}/general");

        var v1 = general.MapGroup("").HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);

        v1.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod);
        v1.MapDelete("{url}", DeleteMethod);
        v1.MapPut("{url}", PutMethod);
        v1.MapPost("/", PostMethod);
        v1.MapPatch("{url}", PatchMethod);

        var v2 = general.MapGroup("").HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v2);

        v2.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod);
        v2.MapDelete("{url}", DeleteMethod);
    }
}
```

##### Option 2 - Groups with Repeat Route Templates

In this approach, the route templates are duplicated in each group for each API version. This may or may not work for you. It's possible that different API versions use different route templates. Once again, adding the API version to the group implicitly applies the API version for all endpoints in that group.

```cs
public class GeneralController : ICarterModule
{
    public void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        var general = app.NewVersionedApi("General");

        var v1 = general.MapGroup("api/v{version:apiVersion}/general")
                        .HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v1);

        v1.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod);
        v1.MapDelete("{url}", DeleteMethod);
        v1.MapPut("{url}", PutMethod);
        v1.MapPost("/", PostMethod);
        v1.MapPatch("{url}", PatchMethod);

        var v2 = general.MapGroup("api/v{version:apiVersion}/general")
                        .HasApiVersion(ApiVersions.v2);

        v2.MapGet("{url}", GetMethod);
        v2.MapDelete("{url}", DeleteMethod);
    }
}
```

#### Issue 4 - OpenAPI Extension Conflicts

The Microsoft OpenAPI extensions do not play nice with the API Versioning API Explorer extensions. Specifically, when you use `WithOpenApi()` it adds an `OpenApiOperation` directly to the endpoint as metadata. That is a flaw in the design. It is possible that an endpoint can serve multiple API versions with different OpenAPI options. Unfortunately, OpenAPI generators, such as Swashbuckle, look for the presence of `OpenApiOoperation` in the metadata. When present, it uses that instance and skips everything else provided by the API Explorer. This may lead you to results you don't want.

I would recommend **not** using `WithOpenApi()` if you are using API Versioning. You can use other extensions that influence OpenAPI such as `WithSummary`, `WithDescription`, `Accepts`, `Produces`, and so on as long as they don't create or use `OpenApiOperation` directly under the hood. Most of the metadata extension methods add metadata only. You don't need to use `WithTags` because the name configured with the `ApiVersionSet` is the name used by default. No need to define it twice, but you can if you want to.

#### Issue 5 - Application Configuration

Your application configuration does not need to reapply the `ApiVersionSet`. It will already be applied through the endpoint configuration with Carter. Putting all of the pieces together, your application configuration should look something like:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services
    .AddCarter()
    .AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
    .AddApiVersioning(options =>
    {
        options.ReportApiVersions = true;
        options.DefaultApiVersion = ApiVersions.v1;
        options.ApiVersionReader = new UrlSegmentApiVersionReader();
    })
    .AddApiExplorer(options =>
    {
        options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

builder.Services
       .AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapCarter();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        options =>
        {
            var descriptions = app.DescribeApiVersions();

            foreach (var description in descriptions)
            {
                var url = $"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json";
                var name = description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant();
                options.SwaggerEndpoint(url, name);
            }
        });

}

app.Run();
```

A key callout here is how `UseSwaggerUI` is invoked. This setup is required to correlate with how the OpenAPI documents will be created as defined in the `ConfigureSwaggerOptions` class. The two sides need to match up.

Finally, you may have noticed that I removed `UseDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified`. This will almost certainly not do what you think it will do; at least, not as shown. This feature is **only** meant for backward compatibility with existing APIs, but is often abused. You are versioning by URL segment, so this option will have no effect. You cannot have optional route parameters in the middle of a template. The same would be true for `order/{id}/items`. This option will **only** have an effect if you also have routes that do not include the `apiVersion` route constraint in them (ex: `api/general/{url}`). I would not recommend doing that for anything beyond backward compatibility.